# CSS: Nav Bar Jumps Around Before Settling

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

first navigate to my site: www.parish.nl

when you click through the main menu using FF the menu functions just great.

however, when you do the same with chrome or IE 11, then you will notice that the elements of the main menu will momentarily bunch and flicker to the left before going to their correct position.

what is even weirder, is that if I force IE and chrome to always go to the server and not use cache it is perfect. Ok, so I clear out the cache of chrome and IE and then reload. Again the menu flickers when running off local versions of the css and js, almost as if running locally is so fast that it renders the nav elements before the css can catch up. But by running off the server, things slow down enough to remove the flicker - but of course this theory must be non-sense, right ? But why is it ok on FF ?

If you look at the source for the page you can see that I have the js loading first off a CDN, then, I load the Bootstrap also off a CDN then my local css.

any suggestions what is happening and what I can do to fix things ?

Many Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it might be because your dropdown menu elements aren't hidden until bootstap runs. At that point the nested UL's are given a new class name which does have a CSS rule to hide them. Try adding this simple rule to your local CSS file:

```
#menu ul.dropdown{
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: You are a mega star - Thank you !!

Comment: my pleasure. enjoy! ;=)